# Social Service on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, support

For one of my classes I have to prove that I have engaged and participated in a form of social service or anything involving in helping a community.

Seeing that I am an active user on Stack Overflow, I was wondering whether it would be possible to get a document of proof from Stack Overflow?

Comment: Print out your edits, suggested edits, answers, reviews, helpful flags, etc.  Or, just provide a link to your account.  It's all there, publicly available.

Comment: I think by 'community', they mean actual people in a direct community and not a virtual community.  If you help people use software/setup a computer so that they can make a resume, etc I think you would get a better reception.  I would be prepare to argue with someone and be rejected if you use SO for this purpose.  Certainly ask first before submitting the information.

Comment: @artlessnoise could be, yes. I'd recommend the OP get clarification on that.

Comment: [coderdojo](http://coderdojo.com/)

Comment: This seems like a good idea. If you wanted to try something in person too, maybe hosting some "hour of code" experiences at a local library or school in December would be useful.

Answer (score 6):

While I think it's awesome that you thought of Stack Overflow first, I'd recommend doing something in person as well. It's really an amazing experience to watch the face of another human change as you help them. You never quite get that experience online.

That said, in addition to your [SO profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269323/1438), you might consider showing off your most helpful answers. I ran a [query that looks at votes *and* anonymous feedback](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/217212/most-helpful-answers?UserId=1297445) and identified two particularly useful answers:

- [How to open LogCat in Eclipse (for Android Debug)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769798/how-to-open-logcat-in-eclipse-for-android-debug/12769815#12769815) (7948 views, score 11, and 8 anonymous upvotes)
- ["Cannot draw recycled bitmaps" when displaying bitmaps in Gallery attached to Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218976/cannot-draw-recycled-bitmaps-when-displaying-bitmaps-in-gallery-attached-to-ad/12239626#12239626) (7864 views, score 13, and 3 anonymous upvotes)

You might also highlight your [three famous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/28/famous-question?userid=1297445).

As [John Carmack might argue](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/18539/has-stack-overflow-saved-billions-of-dollars-in-programmer-productivity) these little nuggests of knowledge add up to siginificant value over time.

Answer (score 3):

The most natural way to do this is to provide a link to your profile, and display your real name and photo there as a form of proof that it's really you.

If your teacher absolutely wants something printed out, you could consider printing out a screen shot of your profile, or perhaps create a [careers CV](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) which comes with a nice PDF printout.